# Although allowing guest users, couchbase requires authentication

Tags: couchbase, pouchdb, couchbase-sync-gateway

I created a couchbase bucket to sync it with ionic 2 app using PouchDB

In the sync-gateway file I allowed guest users :

```
    "users": {
        "GUEST": {
            "disabled": false,
            "admin_channels": ["*"]
        }
    }
```

I was able to access the database normally, adding docs from the app successfully, syncing was working perfectly with all devices.

But after few hours of developing (without any changing in the sync config file!):

- It started to require username and password
- The docs at the bucket were deleted completely!:

[image]

This problem happened twice with the same scenario.

I searched for the reason, but without avail, any help will be appreciated

THANK YOU

Comment: Answered here: https://forums.couchbase.com/t/although-allowing-guest-users-couchbase-requires-username-pass/11496

Comment: Yeah this topic is mine too :D